# How do I use and if statement based around the results of data in html while using python?

Tags: python, html, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to label items in a csv file based on contents in an html which is being scraped using BeautifulSoup. For some items, more information is required to fulfill what is needed to be presented in said csv file.

I am trying to use and if statement to determine what to label something as in the csv file.

Here is the code:

```html
productid_container = container.find('dt', text="Product Id:")
productid = (productid_container.find_next_sibling('dd').text)

if prodictid is 'Bonus':
  productname = ((container["data-product"]) + " Bonus Edition")
else:
  productname = (container["data-product"])
```

and here is the html. You can see where it says bonus, that is what I have as productid:

```html
<dt>Product Id:</dt>
<dd>
  <span class="highlight">Bonus</span>
  <span class="separator">,</span>
</dd>
```

The code later on prints everything to the csv file without adding " Bonus Edition" even when productid is "Bonus".

Is there something I am missing? My current theory is that I am not having it check the string properly, but I do not know where to go from there or if that is even the case.

Comment: Posting your code of how you fetch the 'productid' varibale  may help. More code, more easy to debug.

Comment: why don't you just log if your code runs into the if or the else?

Comment: @lincr: I added some more code as requested, and showed more html as well

Comment: @Florian H: Sorry but I am not sure what you mean by log

Comment: Just `print(productid)` once you get that variable. You will see it won't be `Bonus`

Comment: Gotcha/ So I just tried this, and it comes up with 'Bonus,' 
So I changed it to call for 'Bonus,' and I still get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine whether a product is a bonus or not you can do the following:

```
productid_container = container.find('dt', text="Product Id:")
productid = (productid_container.find_next_sibling('dd').text)

if 'Bonus' in prodictid:
  productname = ((container["data-product"]) + " Bonus Edition")
else:
  productname = (container["data-product"])
```

Comment: BINGO. That was it. I needed to use `in` and not `is`.

Much appreciated